# Increase the default memory and hash, set key limit of redis

Tags: redis

I am writing a JAR file that fetches large amount of data from Oracle db and stores in Redis. The details are properly stored, but the set key and hash key I have defined in the jar are getting limited in redis db. There should nearly 200 Hash and 300 set keys. But, I am getting only 29 keys when giving keys * in redis. Please help on how to increase the limit of the redis memory or hash or set key storage size.

Note: I changed the 
hash-max-zipmap-entries 1024
hash-max-zipmap-value 64 
manually in redis.conf file. But, its not reflecting. Anywhere it needs to be changed?

Comment: Are you by any chance using redis-cli from Cygwin shell? Do you get the same output from the 'keys' command when querying Redis with a Perl or Ruby client? I similar issue back in the day and it had to do with Cygwin not handling large amounts of STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit about the number of set or hash keys you can put in a Redis instance, except for the size of the memory (check the maxmemory, and maxmemory-policy parameters).

The hash-max-zipmap-entries parameter is completely unrelated: it only controls memory optimization.

I suggest using a [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command to check which queries are sent to the Redis instance.

Answer (score 0):

hash-max-zipmap-value keeps the hash key value pair system in redis optimized as the searching for the keys in these hashes follow an amortized N and therefore longer keys will in turn increase the latency of the system.

These settings are available in redis.conf.

If one enters keys more then the specified number then the hash key value pair will be converted to basic key value pair structure internally and thereby will not be able to provide  the advantage in memory which hashes provide so.